# Download excel file In Asp.net MVC 5 missing CSS files

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am developing one application in asp.net MVC 5.0, for reporting purpose. I am making the use of SSRS Reporting Services.
I rendered report in excel format. I make call to reporting services and  rendered  report in "byte[] array" .then I pass this bytes to return file for download excel file. Below is code I wrriten in action :-

```
  public ActionResult RendertoEXCEL(string Parameter,string reportName)
        {
            byte[] ReadRequest = null;
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            ParameterValue[] parameters = js.Deserialize<ParameterValue[]>(Parameter);
            string RptFomrat = "EXCEL";
            SSRSReportManager rptManager = new SSRSReportManager(RServiceURL, RptUserName, RptPassword);
            ReadRequest = rptManager.RenderReport(RDirName, reportName, RptFomrat, parameters);

            return File(ReadRequest, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "Report.xls");

        }
```

and $.get function on button click using jquery

```
function GetConsExcelFomrat()
    {
        jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true
        var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Array as ParameterValue[]));
        var arrays=JSON.stringify(array);
        var url =  '@Url.Action("RendertoEXCEL", "Reports") ?Parameter=' + arrays + '&reportName=' + '@ViewBag.rptName';

        $.get(url, function (res)
        {

            window.location = url
        });

    }
```

Excel file is downloading in my browser window but when I am trying to open file It shows error that **" Problems during load :-Missing File:C:\Content\CSS\Style.css"**  I think file cant get css effect. can anybody have solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Excel you are using ?

Comment: version is Ms Excel 2007

Comment: Are you had a file at C:\Content\CSS\Style.css

Comment: No I dont have files at this location.

Comment: Put Some css  file at C:\Content\CSS\Style.css  and check once

Comment: Still not showing excel in desire format. but It didnt show the error of file missing

Comment: ,Refer this site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750717/asp-net-export-to-excel-error-problems-during-load-missing-css-files

Comment: Refer https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/export-page-to-excel-missing-css-problem.121546/

Answer (score 1):

Change url like this:-
  var url = '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("RendertoEXCEL", "Reports", new { Parameter = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Parameters as ParameterValue[])),reportName = @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.rptName) })) ';

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Click on File in top menu.
2. Click on More options.
3. Click on Advanced in the side menu of the Excel options box.
4. Under the General section locate Ignore Other Applications.
5. Uncheck the check box beside it.
6. Click on OK.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750717/asp-net-export-to-excel-error-problems-during-load-missing-css-files

Comment: @daredevil Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487944/how-to-prevent-css-missing-when-exporting-some-html-to-excel-file

Comment: @Daredevil Refer https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/export-page-to-excel-missing-css-problem.121546/